# SCORM compliant LMS in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-ajax, scorm

I want to develop a LMS with SCORM compliance.What exactly does it mean.Is it that my lms should be able to create SCORM compliant content or does it mean that my application should be able to view SCORM compliant content.And how i'm going to achieve this in DOTNET

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The first thing you need to determine when asked to add SCORM conformance to a system is whether you are really developing "content" or an "LMS". You are developing content if you want to create something that is delivered to other systems. You are developing an LMS if you are creating a system to play content developed by other people. If somebody has asked you to make your LMS SCORM conformant, then they are asking you to create a system capable of importing, delivering and tracking SCORM conformant content developed by others. There are LMS's that output SCORM conformant content as well, but this is a separate capability that is usually referred to as an "authoring tool".

Developing a fully SCORM conformant LMS is no small undertaking. You should start by getting a good grasp of what SCORM is and how it operates. There is a good overview available at http://www.scorm.com/scorm-explained/. There are three high level tasks to undertake. First you will need to create an import mechanism to ingest SCORM conformant content into your system. This involves parsing an XML document called the imsmanifest and it's associated metadata to discover the structure of the content. Next you will need to develop a launch and tracking mechanism to deliver the content. The heart of this system is an ECMAScript (JavaScript) API that allows the content to persist and retrieve data according to the CMI data model. The final step is to develop an implementation of the SCORM / IMS sequencing engine that controls the navigation between parts of a SCORM conformant course (this last step is the trickiest).

In developing a SCORM conformant LMS, be sure to account for the different versions of SCORM. Also remember that not all content is created equally. SCORM is a great specification, but it only gets us about 90% of the way there. There is still some wiggle room for interpretation that you will need to account for as an LMS developer. To develop a truly compatible LMS, you not only need to develop for the letter of the specification, but also for common interpretations of the specification.

Comment: Mike, I am planning to make my LMS a SCORM conformant.I have visited scorm.com and understood SCORM Driver is for creating SCORM packages.But i can't able to get clearly what SCORM Engine and SCORM Cloud are.I want to import,deliver and track the courses in my LMS.Now what(SCORM Engine or SCORM cloud) i have to opt for? Can you guide me on this please?

Comment: @Mike, So being a scorm lover, what do you think is the main reason people say "scorm sucks"?

Comment: @Manoj how far it took you to make a SCORM engine/ whatebver you were making, Content packaging tool / Engine?