# Classic ASP based SCORM Compliant LMS

Tags: asp-classic, scorm

I have my recent E-learning web site developed in Classic ASP. However, I need to incorporate SCORM in my E-learning web site. Does anyone know a sample how to do this?

I'm new in using SCORM and as my research, I've seen example on how SCORM incorporate using ASP.NET but my current develop site is in Classic ASP.

Any suggestions? Please advice.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing you need to determine is whether you are developing a SCORM conformant Learning Management System, or whether you are developing SCORM conformant content.

Comment: Hi, sorry my question is not clear. However, I need to develop a SCORM conformant learning management system.

Comment: In that case, take a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1907523/scorm-compliant-lms-in-asp-net/1908989. Adding a SCORM player to an existing LMS isn't a trivial task and can get deceptively tricky as you get into it and try to start integrating with all the content vendors out there. The ASP platform shouldn't be significantly different from the ASP.Net platform. Conceptually, you need to parse XML, implement a lot of JavaScript, exchange data between the client and server, and implement the logic for rules interpretation engine. All of that should be possible in ASP.

Comment: Hi mike, thank you for your answer. However, I tried to debug the javascript of a sample scorm course but it keeps me giving an error 'Unable to locate the LMS's API Implementation'. How to develop an API adapter? Can you give a basic example?

Comment: If you're just looking to debug a SCORM course, you really want to use an existing SCORM LMS...building your own is WAY more work than you want to get into. There are several free implementations. Google to find SCORM Cloud, ADL Sample RTE, and Moodle...all will give you a free place to test your content.